# Error loading data with SQL Loader from command prompt

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am having problems loading a set of csv data with sql loader. i have a control file that contains the data and i have already created the target table in oracle 10g.

when i run this following command,

```
 C:\Users\lee\sqlloadertest> sqlldr scott/tiger@MYDB,CONTROL='Ad.ctl'
```

it produces

```
SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Sep 11 17:46:43 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 52
```

when i check the Address table, it shows no rows created, meaning the table was not populated

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the sql loader with the log option and see the actual errors.

This is the complete format.

```
C:\Users\lee\sqlloadertest> sqlldr scott/tiger@MYDB CONTROL='Ad.ctl' log=ad.log bad=ad.bad
```

My guess is the records are all failing with a error, which is usually the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the `ctl` file-

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'Masterpiece.csv' BADFILE 'Masterpiece.bad' DISCARDFILE 'Masterpiece.dis'    
APPEND
INTO TABLE ADDRESS
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
(ID, LOCATORDESIGNATOR, LOCATORNAME, LOCATOR, THOROUGHFARE, ADDRESSAREA)
```

`CSV` file (Win formats) sometime contains `"` around the fields. Use the command below to run the `ctl` file.

```
sqlldr scott/tiger@MYDB CONTROL='Ad.ctl' LOG='Ad.log'
```

Check the `bad` and `dis` files for errors and discarded records.

Comment: @ Annjawn do i need to create the bad and dis files? or id just edit the control file with that

Comment: @lee... no you don't. They will be created automatically in case there are errors and or rejected records.

Comment: @ Annjawn, i still got the same result

Comment: @lee can you update your question with sample data from your `csv` file?

Comment: @lee - I have updated the answer to include `log` file. Run using this and the `Ad.log` file will tell you whats going on.